# Excel 2016 on Windows 10 - Snap Scrolling

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, scrolling

Is there any way to disable snap scrolling in Microsoft Excel 2016 so that the "normal" smooth zooming is enabled? Pressing mouse's middle click seems to be a temporary solution but once I middle click again the scroll snaps to grid again.

Comment: Try in *Control panel > System and security > System > Advanced system settings (in upper-left side) > Advanced tab > Settings in Performance box > Visual effects*,and enable (or disable?) "Animate controls and elements inside windows".

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, I meant Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc I disabled the setting "Show animations in Windows". It did not resolve the issue.

Comment: When you say "zooming" do you mean "scrolling"?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate at all, are you able to capture a gif of this behaviour? Are you holding down a modifier key?

Comment: @Burgi Thanks for a reply. No, I meant scrolling with your mousewheel or scrollbar snaps to a row. Not holding any modifier keys either. I only use excel so I can't really show the documents that this happens. I will try to replicate it at home. I think Jeorje's answer sheds some light on the matter. I found elsewhere too that it can't be done and is a "feature" of the new excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be overcome.

It is a feature their MVP's defend on the MS sponsored support site. Defend as in "No one could ever want anything else! It wouldn't be a spreadsheet unless it snapped like that!"

Check:

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9769824-have-excel-scroll-better-when-there-are-large-cell

MS's site for user suggestions.

The Macintosh people DO have the smooth scrolling you, and everyone else, would like. It is in the operating system and Excel does not override it so you can do smooth scrolling.

It is starting to be a bit shocking how many things Excel relies upon the operating system for and is therefore bound by its limitations, even limitations that no longer apply but still affect it because code was written assuming those limits as if they could never improve. The path length possible in a formula for example.

But no, there is absolutely no way on earth to overcome the issue you raise. Everything involving the mouse works while holding mouse buttons down, but the instant you release them, the display snaps to the cell by cell movement. Just grabbing the scroll bar and moving down half a cell... cool while you hold the button down... release it and the full cell pops into the display rather than leaving it stable as it was until some new action is performed. So not even that.

Comment: I thought this might've been the case. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you may toggle Scroll Lock key on your PC or laptop to disable snapping to cell when scrolling.

For Mac OS, press Shift+F14 (depending on settings and OS version) to toggle Scroll Lock.

Comment: I can not getting this to work, can you show how to do this on windows?